# How to handle kattis false input (kattis.com) in Java?

Tags: java

I am trying to solve a problem in kattis.com.

My main question is how should I handle the false input from kattis when my program is tested?

For example:
You have to find the sum of two Integers. Each integer must be between 1 and 100.
Let's say the input is 20 and 12.
The output must be just an integer indicating the sum of the two integers eg. 32

But what should I do if one of the numbers provided, is eg. 200 ?

Should I just print a new line?
Do System.exit(0)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried that on kattis?

Answer (score 2):

The values provided will never be over the range they have specified, neither will it ever be below it. Don't try to validate the judge, it knows best. Your job is to take the input and do what you have been asked to do

Comment: I would hope that validating inputs is one of the things they look for in candidates.

Comment: @AndyTurner, I would also hope that they look for candidates who don't over think a simple problem

Answer (score 1):

In these cases the range is only there to tell you that you don't have to bother with big numbers, or in some cases the opposite. Don't worry about handling the error states.

Answer (score 0):

Throw an [`IllegalArgumentException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html):

> Thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or inappropriate argument.

Comment: Nope; why, what happens? This is what you should do in Java in general.

Comment: This would be dead code as far as the submission is concerned. Competitive challenge sites are about testing algorithms within well-defined input constraints. It's a contrived sandbox environment where you have strict guarantees. It's fine to do this if you want to, but it seems like a waste of time, like trying to keep your face clean at a barbeque-eating contest.